# Do I need additional Google Ad Manager entries in my Google AdSense ads.txt?

Tags: google-adsense, google-ad-manager

I run all my ads through [Google Ad Manager](https://admanager.google.com/) which falls back to AdSense if there's any unfilled capacity (rarely).

AdSense has persistently nagged me to add its ads.txt file to my sites but I'm wondering if this has implications for my ads being served up through Ad Manager?

I've found the support page [Create ads.txt/app-ads.txt in Ad Manager](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7544382?hl=en) which describes options available under a "Admin and then Ads.txt management" menu item that doesn't exist for me. I'm the administrator in Ad Manager but I don't have any linked Ad Exchange accounts, so that explains the lack of relevant menu item.

Are the ads I'm running through Ad Manager at risk of being blocked if I add the AdSense ads.txt file without any additional entries added for Ad Manager?